# Issue in override admin block in magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, override-block

I have override `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Create\Items.php` file, Its overided, When I am executing process, system calling respective `_beforeToHtml()` function from my file.

But at the end of function here is a line of code  -  `return parent::_prepareLayout();`
That creating issue I think because on the page it's showing nothing. And also not giving any error.

Here is code  -

`

```
namespace Customcode\Productserialno\Block\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Create;

class Items extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Create\Items
{
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $onclick = "submitAndReloadArea($('invoice_item_container'),'" . $this->getUpdateUrl() . "')";
        $this->addChild(
            'update_button',
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button',
            ['class' => 'update-button', 'label' => __('Update Qty\'s'), 'onclick' => $onclick]
        );
        $this->_disableSubmitButton = true;
        $submitButtonClass = ' disabled';
        foreach ($this->getInvoice()->getAllItems() as $item) {
            /**
             * @see bug #14839
             */
            if ($item->getQty()/* || $this->getSource()->getData('base_grand_total')*/) {
                $this->_disableSubmitButton = false;
                $submitButtonClass = '';
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($this->getOrder()->getForcedShipmentWithInvoice()) {
            $_submitLabel = __('Submit Invoice and Shipment');
        } else {
            $_submitLabel = __('Submit Invoice');
        }
        $this->addChild(
            'submit_button',
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button',
            [
                'label' => $_submitLabel,
                'class' => 'save submit-button primary' . $submitButtonClass,
                'onclick' => '',
                'disabled' => $this->_disableSubmitButton
            ]
        );
        try{
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
        } catch(Exception $e){ echo $e->getMessage();die;}
    }
}
```

Here I override only "onclick" value of 'submit_button'.

Plz, let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of `return parent::_prepareLayout();` use `return $this;`.
Because you can't call the same parent function again

Answer (score 0):

To return the `parent::_prepareLayout();` you have to call

```
return \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\AbstractItems::_prepareLayout();
```

as you parent class now is the one you extend and the `_prepareLayout()` function doesn't exist.